# How to use two different select queries in same php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to use query and query2 two different select queries together.

How to use it and execute?

**Here is my code**

```php
$query2 = "SELECT advance FROM transaction WHERE adv_date=now()";
$query = "SELECT SUM(s.total) AS totalamount FROM sale s JOIN product p ON ( s.pr_id = p.pr_id ) WHERE s.customer_name = '$customer'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);

$output = '';

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= '<h4 style="display: inline;" align="right"> ' . $row["totalamount"] . '</h4><br> ';
        $output .= ' ';
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    $output .= '<tr>
      <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$output .= '<h4 style="display:inline;" align="right"> ' . $row["total"] . '</h4><br> ';
echo $output; ?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: i am using two different select queries. and how will execute both quries to fetch rows?

Comment: from query1 i have fetched row of total.and from query2 i need advance .also it is to be displayed in h4 tag

Answer (score 0):

try this one it will help you

```
$sql = "SELECT Lastname FROM Persons ORDER BY LastName;";
$sql .= "SELECT Country FROM Customers";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
        }
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood your question right, but i created a function to execute both of your queries, by passing them through the parameter of the function.

```
function commitQuery($query){
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);    
 $output = '';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
  $i=0;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $output .= '<h4 style="display:inline;" align="right"> '. $row["totalamount"] .'</h4><br>';  
    $output .= '';  
    $i++;
  }  
 } else {  
    $output .= '  
     <tr> 
      <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
     </tr>';  
 }  

    $output .= '<h4 style="display:inline;" align="right"> '. $row["total"] .'</h4><br>';  

   echo $output;  
 }
}

commitQuery("SELECT advance FROM transaction WHERE adv_date=now()");
commitQuery("SELECT SUM(s.total) AS totalamount FROM sale s JOIN product p ON ( s.pr_id = p.pr_id ) WHERE s.customer_name = '$customer'");
```